# Using Activity Group

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use ActivityGroup to run two activities, but the catch is that those are not necessarily Activities I wrote, for example, I may want to open a contact picker or something that was part of the system. Is this possible? Using the ndk maybe?

EDIT: I want to run both activities on-screen at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understood your question. But if you want to start an activity from another one, you can simply use:

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(String intent));
```

Were the parameter of Intent should be the component name of a registered activity, the action or a specific class of your application that you want to start.

i.e. to open a contact detail:

```
this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ""+contactId)));
```

take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to have a deep view on intent

Comment: I want to run both activities on-screen at the same time.